# Firebase to work with SystemJS

Tags: typescript, firebase, systemjs

I'm using SystemJS to load all my dependencies. I'm using TypeScript but I something really odd is happening. Firebase is being imported but I can't seeem to call `new Firebase("myUrl") on it.

Here's my map property of SystemJS

```
map: {
        'rxjs': '/node_modules/rxjs',
        'lodash': '/node_modules/lodash/index.js',
        'handlebars': '/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js',
        'firebase': '/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js'
}
```

Unless I'm missing something I can't seem to instantiate a Firebase instance...

`new Firebase("myUrl")` throws a `Firebase is not a function` but the object isn't `undefined`

I upgraded to SystemJS 0.19.6 and Firebase 2.3.2

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you solved it?

Comment: I dumped system JS because of this and several other issues and went with webpack

Answer (score 1):

My SystemJs:

```
'firebase': 'npm:firebase/firebase.js',
```

And there is my code:

```
import 'firebase';

let config = {
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: 
    databaseURL: ',
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: 
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

It is working well with SystemJs.